# Normalization of Generators in SU(N)

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, diagonalization

I have given a finite-dimensional matrix-representation of $SU(N)$. In this representation, the generators are denoted by $G^{a}$ for $a=1,\dots N^{2}-1$. I have to show that I can choose the generators always in such a way that

$$\operatorname{tr}(G^{a}G^{b})\propto \delta^{ab}.$$

How can I show this? One idea would be maybe to use something like diagonalization of the matrix with entries $\operatorname{tr}(G^{a}G^{b})$, but I don't know if this works, because the diagonal entries of this diagonalized matrix could also have different values.....Any ideas?